# How to call a method from one test case by using Katalon Studio?

Tags: katalon-studio

How to call a method from one test case by using Katalon Studio?

For example, I have a test case Purchase order and I have two test methods(test method1 and test method2 in it, Now what I want to do is, I want to create a new test case and call only test method2 in it.

Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

You can simply call an existing test case from a test case with this code:

```
WebUI.callTestCase(findTestCase({Test Case ID}), [key1:value1, key2:value2, … , keyN:valueN], FailureHandling.option)
```

A quick example:

```
WebUI.callTestCase(findTestCase('TestCaseToCall'), [:], FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If that `method2` consist purely of actions on one page, you could implement page object model:

```
package com.yourEntityName.pages;

import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject;

import com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException;
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI;

public class YourPage { 

    public void method2() throws StepFailedException { 
       // ...implementation goes here...
    }

}
```

and just call it from the two test cases:

`new YourPage().method2();`

**NOTE**: a couple things about this:

- this is called a Custom Keyword. More on that [here](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/introduction-to-custom-keywords.html#create-a-custom-keyword).
- there is **no** logging of any of the steps of this method, so you might want to [`KeywordUtil.logInfo()`](https://docs.katalon.com/javadoc/com/kms/katalon/core/util/KeywordUtil.html#logInfo(java.lang.String)) the important steps
- as corollary to second bullet point, git gud at debugging/troubleshooting, and
- make damn sure that whatever code you write here works seamlessly